# How to use Linq to select items from a anonymous IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, ienumerable

I have got 2 IEnumerable Collections that contain a character and the count of the character(ie s1{Key = 'a' Count='5'} and s2{Key='a' Count = '4'})

I want to do the following with a Linq query:

if the item is in both collections, I only want the item from collection with the higher count, ie Count=5 from s1

if the item only is in one collection, then we use that item(can't use Distinct because it says IEnumerable Anonymous doesn't contain Distinct)

if the items are in both collections but their counts are equal, it doesn't matter which one we use.

Cannot figure this part out, I am pretty sure once I see the solution I am going to want to bang my head into a wall...

Comment: Please post sample code that you have tried.

Comment: items.GroupBy(a => a.Key).Select(gr => new { Key = a.Key, Count = gr.Max(aa => aa.Count)) })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by `Key` and select max `Count`:

```
var collection1 = "testtt".GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
var collection2 = "teessst".GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

var result = collection1.Concat(collection2)
    .GroupBy(item => item.Key, item => item.Count)
    .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Max() });
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `Linq` extension functions you could do this.

```
Dictionary<char,int> dic1 = ...;
Dictionary<char,int> dic2 = ...;

var result = dic1.Concat(dic2)
    .GroupBy(g=>g.Key)
    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Max(m=>m.Value)) ;
```

In case if you have two collections of which the underlying type containing `key, count` `fields/properties`, then try using this.

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2)
    .GroupBy(g=>g.Key)
    .Select(x=>new                 // Create an object instead if you have one.   
     {
         x.Key, 
         x=>x.Max(m=>m.Count) 
     };
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ylEig1)

Comment: Why use dictionaries? The OP doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the fairly straight forward:

```
var s1 = new [] { new { Key = 'a', Count = 5 }, new { Key = 'b', Count = 2 } };
var s2 = new [] { new { Key = 'a', Count = 4 }, new { Key = 'c', Count = 7 } };

var result =
    s1
        .Concat(s2)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1));
```

It gives me:

[image: result]

Comment: Can you remove your down vote if you are happy with my update?